# Why button onclick event in JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

When I click on input button, I have nothing in Console, however I expect "Hello".

This is my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-next');
  btn.onclick = function() {
    btn.click();
    console.log("Hello");
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn-next" value=">" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `document.getElementsByClassName('btn-next')[0];` as `getElementsByClassName` will gives the array of elements matching that class name and since you have only one element with that class use `[0]` to get the reference of that element.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-next')[0];
  btn.onclick = function() {
    btn.click();
    console.log("Hello");
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn-next" value=">" />
```

You can also use `querySelector` for the same purpose:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-next');
  btn.onclick = function() {
    btn.click();
    console.log("Hello");
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn-next" value=">" />
```